# HDLCompilers:246 - "numop.v" line 28 Reference to vector reg 'numopout' is not a legal net lvalue

Tags: verilog

In this module I'm verifying the buttons and assigning a value to another variable and sending it to another module which returns the value for the numopout output.
But it says its not a legal net lvalue, I don't know what that means.

```
module numop(
input btn1,
input btn2,
input [3:0] numopin,
output reg [3:0] numopout
);
 reg [1:0] aux;
 loco locovox(aux,numopin,numopout);
always @ (posedge btn1,posedge btn2)
begin
    if((btn1 == 1)&&(btn2 == 0))
        aux = 2'b11;
    else if((btn1 == 0)&&(btn2 == 1))
        aux = 2'b10;
    else if((btn2 == 0)&&(btn1 == 0))
        aux = 2'b01;
    else if((btn2 == 1)&&(btn1 == 1))
        aux = 2'b00;
    else
        aux = 2'b00;
end
```

endmodule

Comment: `numopout` should be defined as a `wire`, not a `reg`.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise or operation. A sensitivity list uses `or` (and since Verilog-2001 `,` is also supported). Therefore:

```
always @ (btn1 | btn2 | numopin[0] | numopin[1] | numopin[2] | numopin[3])
```

Should be:

```
always @ (btn1 or btn2 or numopin[0] or numopin[1] or numopin[2] or numopin[3])
```

or (if IEEE Std 1364-2001 or newer)

```
always @ (btn1, btn2, numopin[0], numopin[1], numopin[2], numopin[3])
```

and can be simplified to:

- `always @(btn1 or btn2 or numopin)` (IEEE Std 1364-1995 and newer)
- `always @(btn1, btn2, numopin)` (IEEE Std 1364-2001 and newer)
- `always @*` (IEEE Std 1364-2001 and newer) *Recommended*

`@*` (or `@ (*)`) is an auto sensitivity list; added in IEEE Std 1364-2001. Any signal referenced in the combinational block and not assigned is considered an input. `@*` is the recommenced wait of describing combinational logic with an always block (unless you are strictly following IEEE Std 1364-1995).

---

`posedge` and `negedge` in the sensitivity list is for synthesizable flip-flops or non-synthesizable behavior modeling. If you have two (or more) edges, a smart (advance) synthesizer will assume any signal in the sensitivity list used in the procedural code is asynchronous. A simple will treat the first signal as synchronous and the others as asynchronous.

*DESIGN GUIDELINE:* only use `posedge` and `negedge` for synchronous flip-flop logic.

One solution (with minimal change) is:

```
always @ (btn1 or btn2)
begin
    if((btn1 == 1'b1)&&(btn2 == 1'b0))
        aux = 2'b11;
    else if((btn1 == 1'b0)&&(btn2 == 1'b1))
        aux = 2'b10;
    else if((btn2 == 1'b0)&&(btn1 == 1'b0))
        aux = 2'b01;
    else // this 'else' handles '(btn2 == 1'b1)&&(btn1 == 1'b1)' for you
        aux = 2'b00;
end
```

But you can simplify the code (same synthesis output) to:

```
always @* begin
  case({btn2,btn1})
    2'b00 : aux = 2'b01;
    2'b01 : aux = 2'b11;
    2'b10 : aux = 2'b10;
    default : aux = 2'b00;
  endcase
end
```

FYI: it is also a bad practices to compare `btn1 == 1` and `btn2 == 0`. This is because `1` and `0` are considered 32-bit values, you should get synthesis warning. It is better to be explicit: `btn1 == 1'b1` and `btn2 == 1'b0`

Comment: It compiles but it says i have to configure clocks, and i dont want it to be a clock, i just want to push a button and that signal goes into my module.

Comment: Sounds like you are inferring a latch in your design and trying to run on a FPGA that doesn't have latches. Latches are caused by missing assignments. For examplie `if(btn1) ... else if(btn2) ...` missing an `else`. There is not definition of what value `numopout` should be if `btn1` and `btn2` are both low; keep previous (a latch) is assumed. Same can happen with an incomplete case-statement.

Comment: I added the missing assignments for the if and case but it keeps telling me btn1 is a clock signal. I added an if(btn1 == 1) else if(btn1 == 0) else if(btn2 == 1) else if(btn2 == 0) and else.

Comment: You do not need additional `else if`, just an `else`. Please update your question with your actual code.

Comment: Updated. I changed my code and tried to use another logic, but now it gives me another error.

Comment: The reason you are seeing btn1 interpreted as a clock signal is because you are posedge btn1 in the sensitivity list. If you just want to create combinatorial logic, then you should use`always @ (btn1,btn2)`.